# Retrieve overpass data with custom poly

Tags: python, overpass-api

Is it possible to retrieve osm data by using [overpass api](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API#Introduction), for a specific boundary area? I have a custom area in poly format (can change it to geojson) and I would like to retrieve the ways edited by specific users.

Is it possible to find the same as above, by other means?

Comment: Have you tried this https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#Select_region_by_polygon ?

Comment: @Nil Thank you, I will have a look. At first look there is a restriction to use with for nodes only. "The only restriction is that polygons can only be used as borders for nodes. Please use one of the various recurse statements to get ways and relations from it."

Comment: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#By_polygon_.28poly.29 is the current documentation, the previously posted link is outdated! There's no restriction to use poly alongside ways or relations.